# How do I access MainWindow XAML components in a separate class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

I have a WPF application where I have the MainWindow.xalm, MainWindow.xalm.cs and a class file called Utilities.cs.  In the MainWindow.xaml I create a form with a side menu that has sub-menus.  I enable and disable the side menus depending on what the user chooses.  I created code in the Utilities.cs class to enable or disable depending on whether true or false is passed.  In the MainWindow.xaml.cs I reference the Utilities.cs class like this:

```
NBFoodPantry.Utilities nbuUtilities = new NBFoodPantry.Utilities();
```

In the Utilities.cs file I reference the MainWindow components like this:

```
NBFoodPantry.MainWindow nbMainWindow = new MainWindow();
```

Here is the start of my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
namespace NBFoodPantry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn;
        string strErrorLogPath, strErrorLogFile, strVCClientIDSelected, strFCClientIDSelected = string.empty;
        string strVCName, strFCName, strVCButtonType, strDBInstance = string.empty;
        bool blnRowSelected, blnUpdateGridLoaded;;
        bool[] blnUpdateFields = new bool[9];
        DataRowView drvRow;
        PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
        PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        bool isWeeklyReportViewerLoaded, isPhoneReportViewerLoaded, isDependentAgeReportViewerLoaded;
       BindingSource dataBindingSource = new BindingSource();

       NBFoodPantry.Utilities nbuUtilities = new NBFoodPantry.Utilities();

       public class Client
       {
           public string Name { get; set; }

           public DataGridRow DGRow { get; set; }
       }



        #region MainWindow
        public MainWindow()
        {
```

Here is the start of my Utilities.cs file:

```
namespace NBFoodPantry
{
    public class Utilities
    {
        NBFoodPantry.MainWindow nbMainWindow = new MainWindow();
```

Here is a couple of the routines that I created to reference the submenus from the MainWindow:

```
public void EnableAddMenu(bool blnStatus)
    {
        nbMainWindow.miAdd.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
    }


    public void EnableAddSubMenus(bool blnStatus)
    {

        nbMainWindow.smiAddCheckinDate.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        nbMainWindow.smiAddMonthlyVisitDate.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        nbMainWindow.smiAddCardIssueDate.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        nbMainWindow.smiAddDependent.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        nbMainWindow.smiAddNote.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
    }
```

Now when I try to run the program I get this message:

```
 "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"
```

on this line of code:

```
PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
```

Any idea why I now get this error?  How do I handle these errors?  The code worked great until I moved my duplicated code to Utilities.cs.

Comment: The loop should be fairly apparent. MainWindow creates a Utilities which creates a MainWindow which creates a Utilities.... The likely (short-term) answer is to pass your MainWindow instance *to* Utilities. The longer term answer is to use a better design like MVVM with proper OOP where these mistakes are at the very least less common.

Comment: #BradleyDotNET -- Do you have any example or explanation on the "better design like MVVM with proper OOP"?  I am self taught on c# and would prefer to learn the correct way to perform these tasks.  Thank you!

Comment: Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654(v=vs.100).aspx (OOP) and then go here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx (MVVM). I can't encourage you strongly enough to also find a good programmer to try and teach you some of this, its hard to pick up on your own. If you don't know any there are paid (and maybe free) mentorship platforms out there. Many of this sites chat rooms can help as well. The two concepts are too big for an SO post unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking #BradleyDotNET's approach.  I have changed my code to this in the Utilities.cs file:

```
public void EnableAddMenu(bool blnStatus)
    {
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).miAdd.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
    }


    public void EnableAddSubMenus(bool blnStatus)
    {
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).smiAddCheckinDate.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).smiAddMonthlyVisitDate.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).smiAddCardIssueDate.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).smiAddDependent.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).smiAddNote.IsEnabled = blnStatus;
    }
```

That is just for now, I am also looking at the MVVC approachto learn the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new instance of the MainWindow class in your Utilities class you could inject the Utilities class with a reference to the already initialized instance of the MainWindow class. You will need a reference to this particular instance to be able to enable and disable any controls in it anyway. Please refer to the following sample code.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn;
    string strErrorLogPath, strErrorLogFile, strVCClientIDSelected, strFCClientIDSelected = string.empty;
    string strVCName, strFCName, strVCButtonType, strDBInstance = string.empty;
    bool blnRowSelected, blnUpdateGridLoaded;;
    bool[] blnUpdateFields = new bool[9];
    DataRowView drvRow;
    PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
    PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    bool isWeeklyReportViewerLoaded, isPhoneReportViewerLoaded, isDependentAgeReportViewerLoaded;
    BindingSource dataBindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public class Client
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DataGridRow DGRow { get; set; }
    }

    NBFoodPantry.Utilities nbuUtilities;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nbuUtilities = new NBFoodPantry.Utilities(this);
    }
}
```

**Utilities.cs:**

```
public class Utilities
{
    NBFoodPantry.MainWindow nbMainWindow;

    public Utilities(NBFoodPantry.MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        nbMainWindow = mainWindow;
    }
}
```